# Django extending model post_save

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-signals

triyng to extened my model with post_save:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def create_account_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        account_profile = Account.objects.create(account=kwargs['instance'])



post_save.connect(create_account_profile, sender=Account)
```

getting the following error:

```
Account() got an unexpected keyword argument 'account'
```

solution:

```
def create_account_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        account_profile = Profile.objects.create(account=instance)


post_save.connect(create_account_profile, sender=Account)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a new Account object you need to send the related_name from the Account model and not Profile.

```
def create_account_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        account_profile = Account.objects.create(profile=instance)
```

What I understand is that you want to create the associated Account object when you create a Profile ?

if so your post_save is not using the right sender ?

```
post_save.connect(create_account_profile, sender=Profile)
```

Comment: @Arik can you update if my answer was correct or not ?

Comment: your answer is not correct. getting: Cannot assign "<Account: first_name last_name>": Account.profile" must be a "Profile" instance.

Comment: Now it lets me save an account without errors, but the profile is not save automatically at it's model.

Comment: I've figure that out, thank you for the help. welcome to look at the edited original code.